# Component is not unmount after its delete in store

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Project (Todolist) was created with `immutable` library, [source here](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/react-test)

Store structure: `project` have many `tasks`, In redux store: `State` - map, `projects, tasks` - Records

When I asyncly remove project ...

```
export const removeProject = project => (dispatch) => {
  if (!isProjectExist(project)) return Promise.resolve()
  return projectService
    .delete(project)
    .then(
      () => {
        dispatch(remove(project))
        console.log("post removeProject resolved")
      },
      handleError,
    )
}
```

.... that was created after initialization - it will be deleted and properly unmounted, but when project was passed as `initialState` -  `ProjectList` will not be rerendered, and `ProjectItem` try to render itself with stale data, and fail, as in picture [image]

---

[It have tests](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/react-test/blob/master/spec/javascripts/actions/projectActionsSpec.js)

---

It looks like reducer returs changed data, but I use immutablejs, and previously i use `normalizr-immutable`, but I thought that source of issue in this library and write my own `normalizeInitialState` ([source](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/react-test/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/normalizers.js)), it did not help, now I think that maybe source of problem in `redux-immutable`

---

I struggled entire day on solving of this problem

---

[creator of redux says](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/86#issuecomment-137160004)

> I don't think this is something we can fix. React state changes are
>   asynchronous and React may (or may not) batch them. Therefore, the
>   moment you press “Remove”, the Redux store updates, and both Item and
>   App receive the new state. Even if the App state change results in
>   unmounting of Items, that will happen later than mapStateToProps is
>   called for Item.
>
> Unless I'm mistaken, there is nothing we can do. You have two options:
>
> Request all required state at App (or a lower, e.g. ItemList) level
>   and pass it down to “dumb” Items. Add safeguards to mapStateToProps
>   for “currently unmounting” state. For example, you may return null
>   from render in this case. Potentially we could have the component
>   generated by connect() return null from its render if mapStateToProps
>   returned null. Does this make any sense? Is this too surprising?

Hm, I never saw stubs like `return (<div></div>)` or safeguards in mapStateToProps in others code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

markerikson

> I'm not entirely sure I follow what exactly your problem is, but as a
>   guess: it sounds like the child component is re-rendering before the
>   parent is. This is a known issue with React-Redux v4 and earlier. The
>   v5 beta fixes that issue. Try installing react-redux@next and see if
>   that takes care of your problem.