# Redux async dispatch causes connected component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

When a button is clicked, then an API call is made (simulated by setTimeout) and when complete, that item is removed from the state. I would expect the component to not attempt to be rendered, but it is and fails, because the state it needs is no longer there.

[The first fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nickkell/macmahne/3/) showing the desired behaviour works because the call to dispatch is synchronous:

```
dispatch({
  type: 'REMOVE',
  id
});
```

[The second fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nickkell/macmahne/4/) shows the error because the call to dispatch is made asynchronously:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'REMOVE',
    id
  });   
 }, 0);
```

I assumed the parent component would no longer try to render the child component because that item has been filtered out of the array. How do I remove the item from the state and prevent the component trying to re-render?

Comment: [Similar to this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823843/component-is-not-unmount-after-its-delete-in-store). Upgrading to react-redux@next solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is an issue because by default redux doesn't support async calls like so what you are looking for it redux-thunk

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Scroll down to motivation and it will basically have the exact same code you have posted here.

:::EDIT:::

Based off of your comment below I updated your code I think one of the main sources of the problem was connecting the Item component with map state to props.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, { id }) => {
    var {text} = state.items.filter((x) => x.id === id)[0];
    return {
    id: id,
    text: text
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
    onRemove(id) {
        setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'REMOVE',
          id
        }); 
     }, 0);
    }
  };
 };
```

I know you probably didn't need it / or want it but I refactored the code a little bit to make it a little more clear but I might have gotten carried away and took it to far from your original example but if you want to take a look its posted here.

https://jsfiddle.net/kriscoulson/ogkyspsp/

Comment: I thought the middleware was just allowing you to use action creators asynchronously, but I'd rather do it without. Is the middleware doing something magic behind the scenes? I've [updated the example here](https://jsfiddle.net/nickkell/macmahne/5/) to use redux-thunk and it still isn't working...

Comment: @NickL I updated my answer above a little bit. Sorry if I was unclear the first time. I may have went to far from your original question. But made it work with with the settimeout without reduxthunk

Comment: So it's as a consequence of connecting that component to the store? The reason I did it that way is for performance in my application, to minimize re-rendering (it's a table, with the rows and cells connected to the store). I was following [this tree example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/tree-view). 
I still want to connect the components to the store, is this possible? Do I first have to dispatch actions to remove all child items first?

Comment: [Here is an example that works](https://jsfiddle.net/nickkell/macmahne/6/). It dispatches two actions: the first hides the item, and the second removes it from the state. This doesn't feel intuitive, as normally I'd just remove the tree starting from the node to be deleted, rather than traversing the tree and deleting upwards...

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply I updated my version but instead of reconnecting the Item Component and searching for the id again on every item. But you can use the `shouldComponentUpdate` method if you remove from my example it will show that it works and the Item Component does rerender. Also it doesn't matter what the html mark up is so you can still use a table. 
https://jsfiddle.net/kriscoulson/ogkyspsp/1/